# A triangle with three cevians

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> The figure to the right shows a triangle with three cevians drawn through an interior point, and all perimeter segment lengths are given in meters. What is the value of s?

[image]

I'm not sure if there is any significance in all three ceva meeting at one point within the triangle... I feel like there might be, but I don't see how to utilise this fact.

I thought using heron's formula and then comparing it to another way of getting the triangle's area. However, I'm not sure how I can get the triangle's area the second (unknown) way.

Perhaps I could use triangle inequality, but that doesn't seem to get me very far, either.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know Ceva's theorem? Acording to that theorem we have:

$${s\over 5}\cdot {4\over 3}\cdot {4\over 2}=1$$

so...